# Bootstrap Nav Bar Not Responding

Tags: bootstrap-4, django-templates, navbar

I'm trying to incorporate Bootstrap into a Django project. However, I can't get the navbar button to ever expand after clicking it. I'm suspecting there's something going on with the Django layering through the templates that is causing Jquery to load strange, and so never do anything when the button is clicked.

Below is my **content_base.html**.

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href={% static 'css/customizations.css' %}>
</head>
<body>
<!-- NavBar -->
<header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href={% url 'home_page:home_page' %}>Home Page</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
                data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
                aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <!-- Needs the users form path for login when created, filler for now to home -->
                    <a class="nav-link" href={% url 'home_page:home_page' %}>Testing</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href={% url 'home_page:about_page' %}>Another Test</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
{% block content %}
{% endblock content %}

<!-- BOOTSTRAP CDN URLs -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-w1Q4orYjBQndcko6MimVbzY0tgp4pWB4lZ7lr30WKz0vr/aWKhXdBNmNb5D92v7s"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- MATHJAX CDN URLs -->
<!--For notes on MathJax CDNs and recommended practices for using the CDNs
https://docs.mathjax.org/en/v2.7-latest/start.html-->
<script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es6"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" async
        src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.7/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And then a content file would extend the above and look like **example_content.html**:

```
{% extends 'content_base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <head>
        <title>A page title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div>
        <h1>Some Heading</h1>
---
---
    </div>
    </body>
{% endblock %}
```

I've removed the mathjax stuff but it didn't change anything. I also tried to just pull down the various JS sources and load them locally and still nothing. Any help is greatly appreciated, this seems like it should have been simple yet I've been wrestling for hours with this.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working this morning. These two were the culprit:

```
data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
```

I changed them to:

```
data-target="#navbarText"
aria-controls="navbarText"
```

Everything worked fine after that.